# Products filter is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i am having a word press bakery website.In the website i have different products in the admin panel i have created different pages with the particular categories but in the front end if i select that product only the products related to that particular categories.

Here is the URL of my site:

dev.rakshanascakes.in

I have filter options for Birthday Cakes .But here it is  displaying blank not displaying any products.

I have with YITH plugins,product filter by clearing cache and all but also it is not working.Can anyone look into this and tell me what is the problem.
[image]

Comment: you have to add the archive in menu http://dev.rakshanascakes.in/product-category/birthday-cakes/.  from http://dev.rakshanascakes.in/birthday-cakes/

Comment: http://dev.rakshanascakes.in/birthday-cakes/ but when i open it from the menu it is displaying the url in this format

Comment: you have to add the menu from archive-product. not a page

Comment: @vel i have created a page and linked the page directly to menu

Comment: @vel can you tell me how to add archive-product in the menu setting there is no option for archive one so

Comment: you can see product-categories in menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Go to appearance->menu

**2.** select the product-categories.
    you can see all the product categories.

**3.** add the menu from product categories

> If not displaying product-categories in menu list.

1. Go to screenoption at the top right.
2. select the product categories

[image]

[image]

Comment: But for me it is not showing the option product categories in the appearence menus.

Comment: I have image how it is looking in appearence -> menus page

Comment: please check the second image above

Comment: Glad to help you